# How to get WooCommerce terms and conditions page URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have a multilingual WooCommerce website and I need to display a dynamic link for terms and condition. I know that I can display the privacy policy link like that:

```
<?php echo get_privacy_policy_url() ?>
```

Does anyone know how to do it for the terms and conditions page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this simple line to get WooCommerce term and condition page URL:

```
<?php echo get_permalink( wc_terms_and_conditions_page_id() ); ?>
```

Tested and works.

Related: [How to get "Terms & Conditions" Page ID in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333105/how-to-get-terms-conditions-page-id-in-woocommerce/63333323#63333323)